# Running drush site-install on Windows

Tags: drush, 8, installation

I ran the following commands:

```
drush dl drupal-8 --drupal-project-rename=drupal_8
cd drupal_8
drush site-install standard --account-name=****** --account-pass=******** --db-url=mysql://*****:******@localhost/drupal_8 --site-name=Drupal_8
```

in windows 7 but I get following error:
Drush 6.7.0 does not support Drupal . See [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) for more information.

Command site-install needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this

command.
The drush command 'site-install standard' could not be executed.

Am I doing something wrong or drupal 8 standard installation is not supported by drush yet?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize that I need to upgrade my drush to 8.0.1 as drush 6.7 won't work with drupal 8.